# REGEX Pattern matching Error (Strings) In JAVA

Tags: java, regex

REGEX pattern:

```
Pattern BASIC_GRAMMAR = Pattern.compile("^((NONTERMINALASSIGNMENT|TERMINALASSIGNMENT)[NONTERMINAL|TERMINAL|PIPE]+)+$");
```

String that is passing that should not be:

```
NONTERMINALASSIGNMENTNONTERMINALTERMINALNONTERMINALASSIGNMENTTERMINALPIPETERMINALERROR
```

There is "ERROR" at the end and should not pass the check but it does.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Search for the Oracle Java Regex tutorial. The square brackets denote character classes and do something entirely fifferent from what you think they do.

Comment: I think you need to use `\b` to match the whole words have a look at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Pattern:

```
Pattern BASIC_GRAMMAR = Pattern.compile("^((NONTERMINALASSIGNMENT|TERMINALASSIGNMENT)(NONTERMINAL|TERMINAL|PIPE)+)+$");
```

Thanks for all the looked.